# Jave : email with pdf attached file : no object DCH for MIME type application/pdf

Tags: java, email

I want to send a pdf file in an email with javax mail.
Below, baos is a ByteArrayOutputStream.

```
byte []  data=   baos.toByteArray();
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
output.write(data);     
output.close();
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(fileName);
attachBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source, "application/pdf"));
attachBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
multipart.addBodyPart(attachBodyPart);
message.setContent(multipart, "text/html");
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(host, from, pass);
transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
transport.close();
```

I am getting this exception when I try to send the email :

> javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
>   nested exception is:  javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException:
>   no object DCH for MIME type application/pdf

I don't know what's wrong here.
If someone does...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this link. I hope it helps you https://community.oracle.com/thread/1589678

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource dataSrc = new ByteArrayDataSource(baos.toByteArray(), "application/pdf");
attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSrc));
attachment.setFileName("myPdfDocument.pdf");
multipart.addBodyPart(attachment);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime I do this I use byte array directly without working through file:

```
byte []  data =   baos.toByteArray();
MimeBodyPart attachBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
attachBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
attachBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);
attachBodyPart.setContent(data, "application/pdf");

multipart.addBodyPart(attachBodyPart);
```