# javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type image/png on trying to send email

Tags: java, email, java-14

I updated my project from Java 8 to 14. I also updated a bunch of dependencies in my project pom.xml. Now I have a problem whenever I try to send an email via the application. I tried many different solutions that I found online but none of them seems to work for me. Here is the error log:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type image/png
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1365)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:88)
    at 
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type image/png
    at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:885)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:316)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1687)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:991)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:561)
    at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:84)
    at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:883)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:316)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1687)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1906)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1315)
    ... 16 more
2020-09-02 17:00:03 INFO  EmailDirectSignOneTimeLogin:79 - direct sign url: http://localhost:3000/direct_sign/czDSIg3Fms
FINISHED JOB
```

Any help would be appreciated. If you need more info, please comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

This could use more information about what you're trying to do, but I happened to find this question while working on the same issue and also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933145/jave-email-with-pdf-attached-file-no-object-dch-for-mime-type-application-pd) and got the code below that works in Java 11:

```
            part = new MimeBodyPart();
            ByteArrayDataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(logoBytes, "image/png");
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(source);
            part.setDataHandler(handler);
            part.setHeader("Content-ID", "<Logo>");
            multipart.addBodyPart(part);
```