# How to add a logo from classpathresoure to email body using MimeMessage in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
public String emailOnRNew(EmailStructureDTO emailStructure, byte\[\] overhaulPdfContent, String contactNumber,
String fromList) {

        String sender = fromList;
        String bcc = CommonConstant.INSP_EMAIL_BCC;
        String content = emailStructure.getEmailBody();
        String subject = emailStructure.getEmailSub();
    
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", environment.getProperty("spring.mail.host"));
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", environment.getProperty("spring.mail.port"));
    
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);
    
        try {
            //*********************************added new part 
            
            MimeBodyPart logoPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("image/logo1.jpg");
            logoPart.setContent(classPathResource.getInputStream(), "image/png");
            logoPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "logo1");
    
            //*********************************
            
            MimeBodyPart textBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            textBodyPart.setContent(content,"text/html;charset=utf-8");
    
            // write the PDF content to the output stream
    
            ByteArrayDataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(overhaulPdfContent, "application/pdf");
            MimeBodyPart pdfBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            pdfBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSource));
            pdfBodyPart.setFileName("Overhaul & Repair.pdf");
    
            MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart();
            mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(textBodyPart);
            mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(pdfBodyPart);
            mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(logoPart);
    
            InternetAddress iaSender = new InternetAddress(sender);
            InternetAddress iaBcc = new InternetAddress(bcc);
            String[] to = emailStructure.getEmailTo();
            String[] cc = emailStructure.getCcList();
    
            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[to.length];
            if (to.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++) {
                    addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
                }
            }
            InternetAddress[] addressCc = new InternetAddress[cc.length];
            if (cc.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < cc.length; i++) {
                    addressCc[i] = new InternetAddress(cc[i]);
                }
            }
            MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
            mimeMessage.setFrom(iaSender);
            mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
            mimeMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
            mimeMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, addressCc);
            mimeMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, iaBcc);
            mimeMessage.setContent(mimeMultipart);
            
    
            Transport.send(mimeMessage);
    
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new DAOException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    
        return CommonConstant.STATUS_OK;

}
```

ERROR : **javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type image/png**

I'm attempting to add a logo to the email body's signature, but it appears above the message.

Also HTML is <img src="cid:logo1">

Comment: please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63708434/javax-activation-unsupporteddatatypeexception-no-object-dch-for-mime-type-image#63715937